# How we can test the vesting config given to chainspec.rs by unit testing?

Tags: pallet, unit-tests, vesting-balance

I have added the vesting schedule/config to the and passed it to config of vesting pallet in chainspec.rs
Can we test the vesting schedule/configs by unit test cases?
if yes can you provide any sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you are testing the Substrate framework. (maybe you want it more security)

Otherwise, testing the data which was passed to the vesting genesis configuration is enough.